# Simple inequality involving product

Tags: analysis, inequality, products, young-inequality

I stumbled across the inequality below, which should be correct...I can't come up with a proof (so frustrating :S). Maybe someone can help?
Thanks a lot!

For $a\geq 0$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$

$$ab\leq a\log{a} - a + e^b.$$

(sorry for the simplicity... I am a bit out of practice)

Comment: Drawing it (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8iiyftmiig) hints in proving that $ab$ is actually a tangent to the convex curve $f(a,b)$ on your rhs. I haven't developed further but probably an interesting starting point.

Comment: (1) Consider $a=e^b$ , we will get Equality. (2) Question should exclude $a=0$ because (2A) $e^b$ is not Zero & (2B) $\log 0$ is invalid !

Comment: Set $c=e^b>0$ and the conclusion follows from $\log x\leq x-1$ when $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of proving such inequalities without thinking too much, is by considering the extrema.

Move everything to to the r.h.s. and consider the function
$$f(a, b) = a\log a - a + e^b - ab$$
We would like to prove that $$f(a, b) \ge 0,\; (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$$
If $a = 0$, then $f(0, b) = e^b$ (by continuity $a\log a = 0$), so in this case clearly $f(0, b) > 0$. From now on we can assume $a > 0$.
Let's minimize $f$ for a fixed $a$. Since exponent grows faster then linear function, $f(a,b) \to +\infty$ when $ b \to +\infty$. If $b\to-\infty$, then $e^b - ab \to +\infty$ because $a > 0$, so we also have $f(a,b) \to +\infty$. Thus the minimum of $f$ occurs at an extremum
$$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b} = e^b - a = 0 \Rightarrow b = \log a$$
Plugging in this point to compute the minimal value for a fixed $a$, we obtain
$$f(a, \log a) = a\log a - a + a - a\log a = 0$$
Since this is a minimum, for all other points $b$ we must have $f(a, b) \ge 0$. Since this is true for any $a$ we have proved the inequality.

**P.S.**
If you want to think even less, you can just minimize $f$ directly as a function of two variables. But then you have to prove that the extrema aren't reached on the boundary/at infinity, which seems to be harder for this particular problem.